# Hydrostatic problem that involves integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I hope you are having a great day, I am learning integral calculus and our teacher left us an interesting problem, however, I don't really understand how to pose the integrals he asked me for.

The question:

The figure shown below represents the cross section of a submersible and some of its dimensions. The green region is a parabolic segment that cuts the $x$-axis at point $A = (-\sqrt{20}, 0)$ and has a vertex at point $B = (0,-2)$. The red region is a semicircle of radius $1$ and centered at $(3, -1)$. Based on this scheme, propose the integral that computes the hydrostatic force on the cross section of the submersible, when it is at 500m, 1000m, 1500m, 2000m, and 2500m, respectively.

So I know that we can define the integral as: $F = \int_a^b \rho g h(x) \, dA$.

But, in this case, we need both functions, how can I get to that integral.

Thank you, and have a great day.

[image]

Comment: "we need both functions"? Which two functions do you mean?

Comment: The green parabola and the semicircle i think? @DavidK so we can integrate

Comment: We can guess that $\rho$ is probably density and $g$ is probably the acceleration due to gravity (although you should have said so, explicitly). But what is $h(x)$? What is $a$? What is $b$? How do you proposed to integrate $dA$ from $a$ to $b$?

Comment: @DavidK, for the green part the limits of integration would be (-√20) and (√20) the problem here is that we dont have the parabola function; for the red region i think the equation would be x = sqrt(1-(y+1)^2) +3 so the limits would be -2 to 0

Comment: You know two points on the parabola, and that one of them is the vertex. So you know where the parabola has its axis of symmetry, which tells you $(\sqrt{20},0)$ also lies on the parabola (if you were to continue drawing it past $x=0$, that is). This is sufficient information to find its [equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=parabola+through+%28-sqrt%2820%29%2C+0%29+and+%28sqrt%2820%29%2C+0%29+and+vertex%280%2C-2%29). The semicircle is laid out for you.

Comment: What precisely is $dA$ here?  What is $h(x)$? (I don't mean a formula; I mean a description of what this is in terms of the geometry of the problem.) Isn't the hydrostatic force at depth $y$ proportional to $y$? Is your $x$ in fact the vertical coordinate $y$?

Comment: I think a large part of the purpose of this exercise is for you to be able to understand what a formula like $F=\int_a^b \rho g h(x)\,dA$ means in a context like this, which implies that you should be able to explain to us what each part of the formula means and how they work together, independently of a particular cross-section. This is what the last comment (and my similar comment earlier) are asking you to do. At this point I'm not even sure the formula you wrote in the question is the correct formula.